# Apply column filter on summed columns in DB2

Tags: sql, db2, aggregates

I have the following DB2 table:

| COLUMN_NAME | DATA_TYPE | TYPE_NAME | COLUMN_SIZE | COLUMN_TEXT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DMPROD | -2 | CHAR () FOR BIT DATA | 35 | Product Code |
| DMPTYP | -2 | CHAR () FOR BIT DATA | 1 | Period Type |
| DMTYPE | -2 | CHAR () FOR BIT DATA | 6 | Type of Data |
| DMVL01 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 1 |
| DMVL02 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 2 |
| DMVL03 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 3 |
| DMVL04 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 4 |
| DMVL05 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 5 |
| DMVL06 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 6 |
| DMVL07 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 7 |
| DMVL08 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 8 |
| DMVL09 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 9 |
| DMVL10 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 10 |
| DMVL11 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 11 |
| DMVL12 | 3 | DECIMAL | 17 | Value Period 12 |
| DMYEAR | 3 | DECIMAL | 4 | Fiscal Year |

Below query would return the sum of value periods for each DMTYP:

```
   SELECT
    D.DMPROD,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSGSV' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS COST,    
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNCST' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS RTNCST,  
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNNET' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS RTNNET,  
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNQTY' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS RTNQTY,  
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNVAL' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS RTNVAL,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSGSV' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS SLSGSV,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSLST' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS SLSLST,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSNIV' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS SLSNIV,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSNTN' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS SLSNTN,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSQTY' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS SLSQTY,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'XXD' THEN D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05 + D.DMVL06 + D.DMVL07 + D.DMVL08 + D.DMVL09 + D.DMVL10 + D.DMVL11 + D.DMVL12 END) AS XXD
FROM
    DWM D
WHERE
    D.DMYEAR IN (2022)
    AND D.DMPTYP = 'M'
GROUP BY
    D.DMPROD
ORDER BY
    1;
```

Output is what I want, except value periods cannot easily be changed in this query without rewriting all sums. For example, say I only want to see  Value Period 1-5 in DMYEAR 2022, I would need to change every case statement. Would there be an easier way, perhaps with subqueries, to keep the SUM statements the same but select only the desired value periods for the final output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this using a subquery:

```
SELECT
    D.DMPROD,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSGSV' THEN val END) AS COST,    
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNCST' THEN val END) AS RTNCST,  
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNNET' THEN val END) AS RTNNET,  
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNQTY' THEN val END) AS RTNQTY,  
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNVAL' THEN val END) AS RTNVAL,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSGSV' THEN val END) AS SLSGSV,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSLST' THEN val END) AS SLSLST,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSNIV' THEN val END) AS SLSNIV,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSNTN' THEN val END) AS SLSNTN,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSQTY' THEN val END) AS SLSQTY,
    Sum(CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'XXD' THEN val END) AS XXD
FROM (SELECT D.*,
             (D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05) as val
      FROM DWM D
     ) D
WHERE D.DMYEAR IN (2022) AND D.DMPTYP = 'M'
GROUP BY D.DMPROD
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I made a stab at what I think you were asking to get:

```
   SELECT 'SLSGSV' as DMTYPE,1 as DMVL01,2 as DMVL02,3 as DMVL03,4 as DMVL04,5 as DMVL05 INTO #temptable
   DECLARE @sumvariable INT

SELECT @sumvariable = SUM(D.DMVL01 + D.DMVL02 + D.DMVL03 + D.DMVL04 + D.DMVL05) 
FROM
    #temptable D
SELECT
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSGSV' THEN @sumvariable END AS COST,    
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNCST' THEN @sumvariable END AS RTNCST,  
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNNET' THEN @sumvariable END AS RTNNET,  
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNQTY' THEN @sumvariable END AS RTNQTY,  
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'RTNVAL' THEN @sumvariable END AS RTNVAL,
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSGSV' THEN @sumvariable END AS SLSGSV,
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSLST' THEN @sumvariable END AS SLSLST,
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSNIV' THEN @sumvariable END AS SLSNIV,
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSNTN' THEN @sumvariable END AS SLSNTN,
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'SLSQTY' THEN @sumvariable END AS SLSQTY,
        CASE WHEN DMTYPE = 'XXD' THEN @sumvariable END AS XXD
FROM #temptable
```

My Understanding is that you would be setting the variable based on the year need.